# Finding number of real solutions

Tags: calculus, functions

The question is to  find number of real solutions of $F(x)=x^3+1=2\sqrt[3]{2x-1}=G(x)$

So first i tried to find the roots of it's derivative , which was not helpful as the equation formed was hard to solve. Then i tried to visualize the graph which was again not very helpful.

Luckily i found the above equation is true for $x=1$. At $x=0$, $G(x)$ is under $F(x)$ but it's derivative is greater than $F(x)$ till $x=1$ (easy to show). And at $x=1$ also derivative of $G(x)$ is greater than that of $F(x)$, so here $G(x)$ overtakes (not before $x=1$) $F(x)$.

Now after $x=1$, once the $F'(x)$ becomes greater than $G(x)$, it would remain like that so $F(x)$ once again over take $G(x)$ and hence we get 2 solutions of for $x>0$.

Then again when we go from $x=0$ to negative $x$-axis , we will see once $F(x)$ starts decreasing more rapidly than $G(x)$ it would remain that way, so we will get one solution for $x<0$.

So i got the correct answer of $3$. But this is a lucky solution. I would be happy if you can provide me with any type of solution. There should be a better way to solve this problem right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT.-Taking equivalently $\dfrac{x^3+1}{2}=\sqrt[3]{2x-1}$ it is verified that if you made $y=x$ you do have in both sides the same cubic equation; in fact:
$$\dfrac{x^3+1}{2}=x\iff x^3-2x+1=0\\\sqrt[3]{2x-1}=x\iff x^3-2x+1=0$$ so the two curves have its common points with the diagonal $y=x$.

Consequently because it is clear that $(1,1)$ is one of this points the two others are the roots of the quadratic equation $x^2+x-1=0$.

Thus the roots are $x=1$ and $x=\dfrac{-1+\sqrt5}{2}$

Comment: As $x^3+1$ is increasing , only solution is at F(x)=x?(for F(x)=F$^{-1}$(x))

Comment: @aryan bansai: there are three roots and its are given by intersections with the diagonal $y=x$ (a consequence of equal equations above as a result of a remark). Sorry for bad English.

Answer (score 0):

your equation is :
$$\left(x^{3}+1\right)^{3}=8\left(2x-1\right)$$
Where:$$\left(x^{3}+1\right)^{3}=\left(x^{6}+2x^{3}+1\right)\left(x^{3}+1\right)=x^{9}+x^{6}+2x^{6}+2x^{3}+x^{3}+1=x^{9}+3x^{6}+3x^{3}+1$$
So we have:

$$x^{9}+3x^{6}+3x^{3}+1=16x-8$$
$$x^{9}+3x^{6}+3x^{3}-16x+9=0$$
Assume rational roots of this equations are in the form $\frac{p}{q}$ where $p,q∈ℤ$ and $q≠0$, also assume this fraction is in the simplest form ([GCD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor) of $p,q$ is $1$), using [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) implies $p$ must divide $9$ and $q$ must divide $1$, so the whole fractions with these assumptions are:

$$\pm1 , \pm3 ,\pm9$$

Checking them implies $\color{green} {\boxed {x=1}}$ is one of the solutions.

Now you can divide the equation by $x-3$ to get :

$x^{8}+x^{7}+x^{6}+4x^{5}+4x^{4}+4x^{3}+7x^{2}+7x-9$

Also for solving $x^{8}+x^{7}+x^{6}+4x^{5}+4x^{4}+4x^{3}+7x^{2}+7x-9$ I suggest to use [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method), then you can get all the solutions.

For more numericals algorithms (but more difficult ways) you can use  , [Bisection method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method) , [Muller's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muller%27s_method),[Secant method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secant_method),[false position method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regula_falsi)

Comment: $x^{8}+x^{7}+x^{6}+4x^{5}+4x^{4}+4x^{3}+7x^{2}+7x-9=\left(x^2+x-1\right) \left(x^6+2 x^4+2 x^3+4 x^2+2 x+9\right)$ and the second term does not show any real root

Comment: @very nice,I did not thought about that, can you explain how did you know you can factor $ x^2+x−1$?